# Google Computer Engine or Google Cloud Service?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am confused on the PaaS and laaS concept in regards to which is best for native Android apps. I only want to use a server to store images that my application can retrieve using REST. For this purpose, should I be using Google Computer Engine, Google App Engine or Google Cloud Service? There are way too many options. Can anyone provide some clarity please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to store images, use Google Cloud Storage. This is a scalable solution for storing files in the cloud, and it is the most economical solution for storing static content.

Google App Engine and Google Compute Engine provide "instances" - virtual machines for your backend application. If you don't need a backend, you do not need to use either of these services.

UPDATE:

If you need to do something with your images on the server side, however, then you cannot use Google Cloud Storage alone. You will need to have a backend (on App Engine or Compute Engine) that processes images using Google Cloud Storage as a file storage option.

You can read more on various parts of Google's platform here:

[Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/products/)

Comment: Generally, when parsing images that are located on a server are cloud storages used? Sorry, this is my first time setting up the server side stuff.

Comment: What does do something on the server side mean? The only thing I intend to do is upload images and then parse those images into my app. But I guess if I have to ask I should be safe and use App Engine right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "parse those images into my app".

Comment: I am using SAX parser to parse images stored on a server into my app. For operations like this, is a backend needed?

Comment: If you need to do any processing of your files outside of a client, you need to setup a backend (server).